# Не могу получить значение SharedPreferences в другой активити

Tags: java, android

Сохраняю значение в одном активити так:

```
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sPref.edit();
edit.putBoolean(ON_CAMERA, true);
edit.commit();
```

А получаю в другом так:

```
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean bl = sPref.getBoolean(ON_CAMERA, false);
```

Проблема в том, что `bl` всегда равен `false`. Перечитав литературу, заметил, что `SharedPreferences` работает только с одной активностью. Подскажите, как сохранить и получить значение правильно?

**P.S.** Я сохраняю значение настройки, которое равно `true` или `false`(по умолчанию) в одном активити, а в другом должен получить данное значение, в зависимости от которого изменить поведение кнопки.

Comment: вы уверены, что ON_CAMERA у вас одинаковый и там и там?

Comment: @metalurgus, да

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы получить экземпляр класса `SharedPreferences` для получения доступа к настройкам в коде приложения используются три метода:

`getPreferences()` — внутри активности, чтобы обратиться к данным одной активности;
`getSharedPreferences()` — внутри активности, чтобы обратиться к данным на уровне приложения;
`getDefaultSharedPreferences()` — из объекта `PreferencesManager`, чтобы получить общедоступную настройку, предоставляемую Android.

Для доступа к настройкам из любого места приложения, вам нужно использовать второй или третий метод:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

[источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php)