# Вывод токена на экран

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Не могу разобраться с выводом токена на экран, подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка:

```
package com.nowandroid.doubleactivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnActTwo;
    Button btnActLogin;
    EditText usernameField;
    EditText passwordField;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnActTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActTwo);
        btnActTwo.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnActLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActLog);
        btnActLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

        usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(_usernameField);
        passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id._passwordField);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnActTwo:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.btnActLog:
                onLogin();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showAlertDialog(String title, String message) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("api", "close dialog");
                }
            })
            //.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show()
        ;
    }

    public void onLogin() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        //Creating an object of our api interface
        API api = RetroClient.getApiService();

        RegistrationBody body = new RegistrationBody();
        // Bind params

        Log.d("api", usernameField.getText().toString());
        body.setName(usernameField.getText().toString());
        Log.d("api", passwordField.getText().toString());
        body.setPassword(passwordField.getText().toString());

        Call<RegistrationResponse> call = api.loginCheck(body);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Response<RegistrationResponse> response) {
                Log.d("api", "onResponse");

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = (MainActivity.this).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putString("token", response.body().getToken());
                    editor.putString("refresh_token", response.body().getRefreshToken());
                    editor.commit();


                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);

                    Log.d("api", "isSuccessful: true");
                    Log.d("api", response.body().getToken());
                    Log.d("api", response.body().getRefreshToken());

                } else {
                    Log.d("api", "isSuccessful: false");
                    showAlertDialog("login error", "Bad credential");
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("api", "onFailure");
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                showAlertDialog("internet error", "fuck you");
            }
        });
    }
}



package com.nowandroid.doubleactivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = sharedPref.getString("token", "123");

        Log.d("profile activity", token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете запускать IDE, копировать туда ваш код, подключить все либы, дописать весь не указанный вами код и запустить? Может быудет быстрее, если вы скжете где и какая у вас ощибка и покажите логи оной?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб прошу простить, публикую первый раз. Дело в том, что ошибки как таковой и нет, когда ввожу правильный логин и пароль, то перекидывает на нужное активити, но токен не отображается на экране. Получается, что приложение отработало корректно, но задачу не выполняет.)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551524/177345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У каждой активити есть свои `SharedPreferences`. Метод `getPreferences()` возвращает объект класса `SharedPreferences` **уровня активити**.

Таким образом, значения, записанные в `SharedPreferences`, которые были получены методом `getPreferences()`, будут видны только для той активити, в которой они были записаны. Собственно поэтому Вы и не видите во второй активити значения, записанные в первой.

Для решения проблемы можно использовать `SharedPreferences` уровня приложения. Получить их можно методом `getSharedPreferences()`.