# Android sdk SharedPreferences. Не считывает параметр из другого activity

Tags: java, android-sdk, android-shared-preferences

```
SharedPreferences sPref;
void saveVal(String id_val,String val) {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(id_val, val);
    ed.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Address saved"+loadVal("id_address"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

String loadVal(String id_val) {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedText = sPref.getString(id_val, "");
    return savedText;
}
```

В этом activity записываю адрес в id_address, а в другом activity считываю его через LoadVal, но получаю 0. Объясните почему

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551524/177345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `Activity#getPreferences(int mode)` создаёт `xml` файл для хранения пар ключ-значение, доступ к которому есть только у этого активити. Чтобы получить префы с глобальный доступом получайте их так:

`PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`