# SharedPreferences из другого активити

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы SharedPreferences мог быть доступен из др классов.

Comment: Все уже давным давно сделано. SharedPreferences доступны из всего приложения.

Comment: @Эникейщик как мне из другого класса проверить чему равняется .Я просто не совсем понимаю как програмно это сделать

Comment: "Другой" класс или тот же самый - разницы никакой нет. Если не понимаете, почитайте пару мануалов с примерами.

Comment: то есть если я в одном классе создам SharedPreferences то я могу использовать его в др классе или как

Comment: @Эникейщик выше

Comment: Да. Вы хоть что-нибудь почитайте про это.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharedPreferences - это обертка для хранения данных ключ-значение в xml-файле. Создав экземпляр класса в одном месте и сохранив там какое то значение под определенным ключом, вы можете получить это же значение по тому же ключу в любом другом классе (при наличии там `Context`), создав другой экземпляр `SharedPreferences`, потому что любой экземпляр читает из одного и того же файла (для некоторых видов экземпляров `SharedPreferences` необходимо указывать имя файла, куда будет сохранятся значения, тогда для другого экземпляра должно быть указано это же имя)

Есть [три метода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551524/177345), получения экземпляра `SharedPreferences`, которые различаются, насколько "далеко" будет доступна настройка: в пределах одной активити, в пределах одного приложения, для всей системы.

[Узнать больше](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php)