# вычитание с разных активностей

Tags: android

Как я могу сделать вычитание с разных активностей. То есть у меня есть некий баланс на первой активности, на второй активности я пишу число которое вычитается из основного баланса. В итоге когда я снова захожу на основную активность, у меня остается только число из которого вычли. как пример изначально у меня было 3, потом на второй активности вычли 2 и когда я снова захожу на первую активность должно стать число 1. Я посмотрел в интернете создание по принципу калькулятора ,но нигде не упоминается как вычитать с разных активностей и как сделать оставшийся баланс.  Есть предложения?

Comment: Вам нужно место, где вы будете хранить ваше число. Это можно сделать по разному. Сложно сказать как будет правильнее. Наверное, вам подойдёт вариант создания класса, в котором будет статическая публичная переменная. Она будет доступна из всех активити, меняйте её. Главное - не забыть её считать в первой активити после возврата со второй. Это тоже можно по разному сделать. Причём простых способов нет. Разве что в `onResume()` методе активити считывать значение переменной и отображать его где вам надо.

Comment: Речь, как я понимаю идет о финансах? В таком случае все данные вам настоятельно рекомендуется хранить в базе данных. Далее вы можете получать доступ к этой базе из любой активити приложения: читать их, производить изменения (вычисления) и записывать обратно. При этом, сделав запись в базу из одной акивити, вы можете прочитать, что записали туда в другой активити. Создание какого то класса с статической переменной  не подходит, потому что после выхода из приложения все ваши вычисления будут утрачены.

Comment: startActivityForResult - Sapienti sat

Comment: это должна быть не совсем база данных с полными характеристиками. У меня всего одно данное, это число, на второй активности я его просто вычитаю и все, когда возвращаюсь на первую активность должно быть число которое получилось при разности,стоит ли для этого создавать целую базу? причем число я должен менять когда захочу,то есть это может быть например и Edittext, если я захочу туда вписать 100 и на второй активности вычесть 50 у меня должно остаться 50 до тех пор, пока я не захочу его поменять,даже после перезахода в приложение

Comment: Тогда вы можете [использовать SharedPreferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/965561/177345) с видимостью для всего приложения по точно такой же схеме, как и с базой данных. При старте приложения читать последнее сохраненное в преференсы значение, выводить его на экран и потом менять как вам надо, записывая новое. При следующем старте приложения в преференсах будет последнее записанное туда значение