# Android SharedPreferences значение не отображается в другом activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-shared-preferences

Я сохраняю StringSet `putStringSet("set", set)` в текущем activity, его можно получить используя `getStringSet("set", null)`, но в другом activity оно почему-то не получает значение и устанавливает `null`, хотя значение в него внесено.

Сохранение MutableSet:

```
val sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
val ed = sPref.edit()
ed.putStringSet("set", set)
ed.apply()
```

Отображение в другом activity:

```
val sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
button.setOnClickListener {
val localSet = sPref.getStringSet("set", null)
println(localSet)
}
```

Comment: Для взаимодействия между активити [используется другой метод - getSharedPreferences()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551524/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff Ваш вариант помог, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте дать имя настройкам имя, допустим, так:

```
val sPref = getPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Comment: Android Studio указывает на то, что commit() устарел, у меня было прописано apply(), но проблема не решена.

Comment: Тогда придётся ждать, когда кто-нибудь заглянет в свой хрустальный шар  и увидит там ваш код.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Добавил код.